# Is there a language to define (state) the generic structure of systems? (E.g., all systems at our company must have a certain structure...)

Tags: architecture, uml, system, erd, sysml

re: Is there a language to define (state) the generic structure of systems? (E.g., all systems at a company must have a certain structure...)

A dumb question perhaps…
So far, I have used the UML / SysML graphic modeling language to model (define ?) ‘actual’ SW object structures / systems.

But what if I want to define (make a statement of definition of) a *generic* system structure?

E.g., I want to define that all systems at my company must comprise one “system” object, where “system” comprises one or more “subsystem” objects. And so on…

Can I do that in UML or SysML? UML or SysML does not seem appropriate (because they immediately label everything as a class or a block).

Maybe there is a different language for that? (Last time I needed to do something like this, I used Visio…)

Maybe that I need the Entity Relationship Language?

Thanks
Avi

Comment: Have you thought over creating a profile for your needs?

Comment: "A system consists of sub systems". Sounds quite trivial. Do you need a modeling language for this? Actually, the systems modeling language already contains all you need. It doesn't call it "system" though. A Block that has sub blocks _is_ a system.

Answer (score 1):

This is what a composite structure diagram or internal block diagram is for! Such a diagram defines more-specific types for properties that refer to things that must be connected in a particular way.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. I will have another go. 

I am asking how to draw a diagram that is *more* generic (i.e., than blocks) - and not asking how to draw less generic (more-specific, as you say).

(So you answered the opposite of what I am asking, to the best of my understanding.) 

To try to clarify: the block diagram constructs would be fine for this particular purpose, but I do not want «block» stereotype to appear on blocks.  Rather, instead, I would want to be able to define a «system» stereotype and a «subsystem» stereotype.

Comment: But maybe my problem is I don't know my SysML platform (Sparx EA) well enough (or SysML well enough, for that matter). Maybe EA/SysML offers the ability to define new element types , like «system» and «subsystem». And so the diagram will display «system» in the defined elements, rather than «block».

Comment: Why do you need to extend the language to express yourself? What is a specific example of a system in your mind?

Comment: That's the whole point. UML/SysML describes concrete systems - well at least concrete definitions - where the blocks/components (or block/component types, to be maybe more exact) have known given names. 

Whereas what I want to do is to describe *in general* what all systems must look like at my X company. E.g., each component must have exactly one local data store, and input interface, an output interface, and at least one sub-module - or something like that.

Maybe I should be using entity relationship diagrams (ERD)?

Comment: Maybe later I will add an example diagram using ERD (or Visio...).

(How do you upload an image to a stackoverflow question ? Do I have to first host the image on a 3rd party site image storage? The last time I did this on stackoverflow was ages ago.)

Comment: Why can’t you just model this with classes? Anything you can model with ERD can be modeled in UML. “each component must have exactly one local data store, an input interface, an output interface, and at least one sub-module.”

Comment: @avi10000 You need a bit more reputation for uploading directly. However, if you add it as link someone will take care soon.

Comment: > Why can’t you just model this with classes? 
Because this is at quite a high system level, and so at that level, things are not termed as classes.  

Btw, I tried using EA ERD and it is not the best thing for what I am doing. Awkward.

Now, after a work meeting I can now ask a more specific question. It is about Git submodules. I asked it on here on SO: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74924564/in-uml-sysml-what-is-the-best-diagram-type-to-represent-a-sw-strategy-using-git

Comment: A UML class need not map to an OOPL class. I see no problem creating a class called “component” connected to a class called “data store”.