# In UML/SysML, what is the best diagram type to represent a SW strategy using GIT Submodules?

Tags: uml, git-submodules, sysml

When using UML/SysML, what would be the best diagram type to represent a software strategy/structure using Git Submodules?

I am a Git novice, but it seems to me that the UML Package Diagram type is the most appropriate at the GIT level, because “GIT Submodules” sounds to me like a way of organizing your physical code files and file groups (and versions), and so it is a “logical organizational” thing.

And then the individual components should be UML components. And down at the unit level, they should be classes.

What do you all say?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using SysML for software?

Comment: To describe physics a component view is likely the one to take. At least I did that in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The package diagram is a way to structure the modelling space. It is not meant to represent the repository structure (despite the folder-like visualisation).

But of course both are not incompatible: you may structure your model elements in packages that have some sililarities with the component boundaries, and use the same logic for your organizing the repos.

Another approach would be to use a diagram showing the artifacts (source file, library, executable) and their dependency. Nothing prevents you from adding a stereotype for repositories.

Comment: > Why are you using SysML for software?
Ok - good point. I should not. 
Then only UML.